# How to convert web-map website to mobile phone

Tags: javascript, openlayers, css, html5

I created simple web-map application,It works perfect on Desktop,but when I open on mobile or tablet then their is size problem.

[image]
When I open web-map in mobile then all the web-map content size are changed. I also added this html code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
```

in my file but still not showing proper output.

How I convert web-map to responsive web-map.How to test it on local machine.

Comment: does Openlayers example map show the same on your device?

Comment: This is more of a web development question.

Comment: On Desktop shows proper but in mobile size got changed

Comment: did you add that <meta> in <head> tag?

Comment: Yes,But still not working.

Comment: Is it necessary to hide div tags for mobile phone.

Comment: Well, I accessed your page and tried add <meta> then it changed the screen for mobile

Comment: You did like this code <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">

Comment: how you checked on mobile phone.I also wan't to check on mobile.

Comment: read Alex's answer. click the mobile device icon then page become small. after then find <head> on 'elements' tab and rightclick and choose 'edit as html' on the context menu. add the tag and click other area then it applies.

Comment: Yes I have done same procedure.Now displaying only two tabs properly but Mumbai and Delhi  not display  properly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continues from my comment,
[image: the order you will follow]

first, click 1 then shows like below. it looks very small not suitable for mobile resolutions
[image]

move to 2 tab and rightclick 3
[image]

select 'edit as html' and add the <meta> code
[image]

and click outside of the text editor area then it changes the resolutions for mobile device
[image]

Comment: Ok Chase,But in mobile it display like this only.Two divs are overlapping.

Comment: That is your choice for mobile. you can change the styles up to the screen size.

Comment: and the thing you need is no more about map.

Comment: Ya but on desktop shows properly.So same size i can't display on mobile?

Comment: if your mobile devices' screen size is the same as desktop, it'll be the same looking. but mobile devices' screen size is smaller. so you should hide or move it small or something.

Comment: Chase thanks for help,I learned little bit new from you.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

To view the map on a 'virtual' mobile phone or tablet, you can use the Chrome developer tools and click the button 'Toggle Device Toolbar' (see the image below).

What you're asking is a basic web development question, though, and the answer varies depending on what you're using for your UI.

I like using Bootstrap for the UI components of my web map, and I learnt how to put something together by pulling [Bootleaf](https://github.com/bmcbride/bootleaf) apart. Maybe have a look at what Bryan did there. Otherwise, if you have a specific question, ask another one.

[image: Toggle Device Toolbar]

Comment: Thanks,I am new for web development, actually it's my first website.I am using HTML5,CSS and JS. In these langue how i convert it,For mobile application, i need to use bootstrap?

Comment: please is there any idea how to do it,help me anyone.

Comment: You can do it, @SeemaBarate. I don't think people will be able to help. Just keep working on it, and it will be come clear.